# Unit Testing Account controller with ApplicationDbContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing

I am a total beginner to unit testing and am having trouble testing some of my methods in the account controller that use the ApplicationDbContext. I have been following this tutorial:
http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/testing-and-debugging/mocking-entity-framework-when-unit-testing-aspnet-web-api-2 
but I cannot seem to access some of the variables related to an applicationUser. In my account controller I am able to access the Id, Username, email etc that are inherited from its superclass "IdentityUser" but for some reason I cant seem to access these variables in my test controller. I have the followig implementation thus far:

```
interface IStoreAppContext : IDisposable
    {
        DbSet<ApplicationUser> Users { get; }
        int SaveChanges();
        void MarkAsModified(ApplicationUser item);
    }
```

My IdentityModel class:

```
 public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>, IStoreAppContext
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {
        }

        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }

        public DbSet<SportProgram> SportContext {get; set;}
        public DbSet<Exercise> ExerciseContext { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ExerciseImage> ExerciseImageContext { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Store> StoreContext { get; set; }


        public void MarkAsModified(ApplicationUser item)
        {
            Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }
```

I have added the following to my AccountController:

```
 private IStoreAppContext db2 = new ApplicationDbContext();

    // add these contructors
    public AccountController() { }

    public AccountController(IStoreAppContext context)
    {
        db2 = context;
    }
```

In my test project:

```
 class TestProductDbSet : TestDbSet<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public override ApplicationUser Find(params object[] keyValues)
        {
            return this.SingleOrDefault(user => user. == (int)keyValues.Single());
        }
```

The return line above is one of the first places where I have this problem. I have "user => user. " and when visual studio offers my suggestions after the "." all that is given to me from the ApplicationUser class are the variables that I have added and I can't seem to access the ApplicationUser Id, username, email that are inherited from the IdentityUser class. Can anyone help please?

Here is another class in my test project that may help you:

```
class TestStoreAppContext : IStoreAppContext
    {
        public TestStoreAppContext()
        {
            this.Products = new TestProductDbSet();
        }

        public DbSet<ApplicationUser> Products { get; set; }

        public int SaveChanges()
        {
            return 0;
        }

        public void MarkAsModified(ApplicationUser item) { }
        public void Dispose() { }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The key idea here is that you replace EntityFramework access with collections, so that you can use LINQ for Objects instead of LINQ to Entities, e.g. to verify the logic of your queries.

So your `TestProductDbSet` should have a collection member (of `ApplicationUser`), which will act as the database. So you should have some data populated for it.

Then in your unit tests you should create `AccountController` with a `TestStoreAppContext`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So you are saying that I should hard code values, into say a list of ApplicationUsers, in my TestProductDbSer class? But how come I can't access those variables such as Id, username etc that are inherited from IdentityUser class?

Comment: Yes, that's the easiest way of having the data. You can also have a constructor or property for setting/overriding the collection in each test class.

I'm not sure on why you can't see your properties. Any chance they're `internal` and the `TestDbSet` is in another assembly or namespace Have you tried typing them manually to make sure it isn't just some issue with IntelliSense?

Comment: I have made a collection of ApplicationUser and I have created an AccountController with a TestStoreAppContext like you advised. I am getting a null pointer exception in my test method for "Parameter name: Request".  After some searching online I found a solution by adding the following line to my method:
 var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "http://62214/api/Account/Register/Password-1");
            controller.Request = request;
But then I receive a Null Pointer Exception with "Parameter name: Context". //Comment continued below

Comment: I added the following line controller.ControllerContext = new System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerContext(); 
but then i receive the same null error again for the "Parameter name: Request". Any ideas? Can't seem to figure it out. Whole method below in next comment. (Sorry I am hitting the character limit on a comment)

Comment: [TestMethod()]
        public async Task PostRegisterTest()
        {
            var controller = new AccountController(new TestStoreAppContext());
            var item = GetDemoProduct();
            var password = "Password-1";
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "http://62214/api/Account/Register/Password-1");
            controller.Request = request;
            var response = await controller.PostRegister(password, item) as OkNegotiatedContentResult<ApplicationUser>;
            Assert.AreEqual(response.Content.UserName, item.UserName);
        }